# Is the set $A = [-1,1]$, compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

$A = [-1,1]$, $X = \Bbb R$ with $d(x,y) = 1 + |x-y|$ if $x \neq y$, $d(x,x) = 0$

Is this set closed since it has no limit points? Also since it is bounded can we say it is compact?

Comment: What does a small open ball (say with radius $0.5$) around a given point look like in this metric?

Comment: @Arthur isn't it just a singleton?

Comment: Exactly. With that in mind (singletons are open), do you think the space is compact?

Comment: @Arthur it is not compact with that perspective. But it still confuses me if it has no limit points isn't it closed trivially? Or am I wrong about the limit points?

Comment: If singletons are open, then every set is open, and thus every set is closed, including $A$. However, compact does not follow from closed and bounded. It follows from closed and _totally_ bounded (i.e. given any radius, the space can be covered using finitely many open balls of that radius). With regular metrics on $\Bbb R^n$, like the Euclidean metric or the taxicab metric, bounded and totally bounded are equivalent. Not in general, however.

Comment: What seems to be common is people seeing a bounded and closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and deducing from it that it is compact. Well, this is a perfect example to show that this statement is not independent of the topology we give on $\mathbb{R}^n$.